# How to type hint so pycharm can auto-complete a local variable?

Tags: django, pycharm

How can I tell pycharm that the return type of *form.save()* is, in this case, a  *CategoryQuestion* object?

```
def category_ask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryQuestion_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.who = request.user
            question.dat<tab>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pycharm 3, **@type** hinting for local variables is picky, but works.  It must appear on the line after the assignment, and appears to required the triple quote syntax:

```
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save()
            """@type : CategoryQuestion"""
            question.dat<tab>
```

Check out the official docs: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d68026e604

Answer (score 5):

Use "**assert isinstance(x, Type)**" to fake pycharm into knowing the proper type for the local variable.  Pycharm then knows the proper type, and tab completion will work:

```
def category_ask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryQuestion_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question                = form.save(commit=False)
            assert isinstance(question, models.CategoryQuestion)
            question.who            = request.user
            question.date_created<tab>
```

As of pycharm 1.2, unfortunately you can't just use a bare unchecked "**isinstance()**", the assert is required.

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm 3 (not sure about earlier versions) supports type-hinting of local variables (as well as paramters) via **:type** or **@type** docstrings.

```
 def category_ask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryQuestion_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # :type models.CategoryQuestion
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.who = request.user
            question.dat<tab>
```

Check out the official docs: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d68026e604

Comment: Did not work for me Pycharm 3.4. It worked for the integer type as in the docs, but not for a model.

Answer (score 2):

For those using python3.6 and higher:
Type Hinting is now a part of python and works well with pycharm.
You can add a `:` after the name of a variable to hint its type such as `some_varibale: str`. The same rule is applied for arguments.
So, in this case, the variable is hinted to be `CategoryQuestion` this way:

```
question: CategoryQuestion = form.save(commit=False)
```

To know how to type hint a queryset such as `filter` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880544/6026516)

You can also use [django_hint](https://github.com/Vieolo/django-hint) which has type hint classes specifically for Django.