# How to use Python type hints with Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, type-hinting

Is it possible to specify type of records in Django QuerySet with Python type hints? Something like `QuerySet[SomeModel]`?

For example, we have model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    smth = models.IntegerField()
```

And we want to pass QuerySet of that model as param in func:

```
def somefunc(rows: QuerySet):
    pass
```

But how to specify type of records in QuerySet, like with `List[SomeModel]`:

```
def somefunc(rows: List[SomeModel]):
    pass
```

but with QuerySet?

Comment: Check out https://sobolevn.me/2019/08/typechecking-django-and-drf

Comment: You might be looking for SomeModelQuerySet, import it from the same path you import SomeModel from

Answer (score 80):

One solution may be using Union typing class.

```
from typing import Union, List
from django.db.models import QuerySet
from my_app.models import MyModel

def somefunc(row: Union[QuerySet, List[MyModel]]):
    pass
```

Now when you slice the `row` argument it will know that the returned type is either another list of MyModel or an instance of MyModel, whilst also hinting that the methods of the `QuerySet` class are available on the `row` argument too.

Comment: There are `stubs` for django with typed `QuerySet` and models: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs Tutorial: https://sobolevn.me/2019/08/typechecking-django-and-drf

Answer (score 48):

There's a special package called `django-stubs` (the name [follows `PEP561`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/)) to type your `django` code.

That's how it works:

```
# server/apps/main/views.py
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    reveal_type(request.is_ajax)
    reveal_type(request.user)
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

Output:

```
» PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD" mypy server
server/apps/main/views.py:14: note: Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.bool'
server/apps/main/views.py:15: note: Revealed type is 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'
```

And with models and `QuerySet`s:

```
# server/apps/main/logic/repo.py
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

from server.apps.main.models import BlogPost

def published_posts() -> 'QuerySet[BlogPost]':  # works fine!
    return BlogPost.objects.filter(
        is_published=True,
    )
```

Output:

```
reveal_type(published_posts().first())
# => Union[server.apps.main.models.BlogPost*, None]
```

- Complete tutorial: https://sobolevn.me/2019/08/typechecking-django-and-drf
- Types for `django`: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs
- Types for `drf`: https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs

Answer (score 26):

I made this helper class to get a generic type hint:

```py
from django.db.models import QuerySet
from typing import Iterator, Union, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class ModelType(Generic[T]):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Union[T, QuerySet]]:
        pass
```

Then use it like this:

```
def somefunc(row: ModelType[SomeModel]):
    pass
```

This reduces the noise everytime I use this type and it make it usable between models (like `ModelType[DifferentModel]`).

Answer (score 17):

### Update 2023

In [django_hint](https://github.com/Vieolo/django-hint) 0.3.0 you can extend your model and the return type of the common functions of `objects` such as `filter`, `get`, etc. will be automatically detected.

```py
from django_hint import StandardModelType

class SampleModel(models.Model, StandardModelType['SampleModel']):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

### Original Answer

This is an improved helper class of Or Duan.

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet
from typing import Iterator, TypeVar, Generic

_Z = TypeVar("_Z")  

class QueryType(Generic[_Z], QuerySet):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[_Z]: ...
```

This class is used specifically for `QuerySet` object such as when you use `filter` in a query. 
Sample:

```
from some_file import QueryType

sample_query: QueryType[SampleClass] = SampleClass.objects.filter(name=name)
```

Now the interpreter recognizes the `sample_query` as a `QuerySet` object and you will get suggestions such as `count()` and while looping through the objects, you will get suggestions for the `SampleClass`

**Note**
This format of type hinting is available from `python3.6` onwards.

You can also use [django_hint](https://github.com/Vieolo/django-hint) which has hinting classes specifically for Django.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of `django_hint`*

Comment: quick note if someone is using VSCode; this solution works perfectly if response type is surronded by single quotes (don't know the reason); `def my_method(self) -> 'QueryType[MyModel]': ...`

Answer (score 14):

`QuerySet` is a good approach for function/method returning any **queryset** of any models. The Django queryset is iterable. But when the return type is very specific to one model, it may be better to use `QuerySet[Model]` over `QuerySet`.

**Example: Filter all active users of a company**

```py
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from myapp.models import User
from collections.abc import Iterable

def get_active_users(company_id: int) -> QuerySet[User]:
    one_month_ago = (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).timestamp()
    return User.objects.filter(company_id=company_id, is_active=True, 
                               last_seen__gte=one_month_ago)
```

The above function signature is more readable than `def get_active_users(company_id: int) -> QuerySet:`

`Iterable[User]` will also work the type checker will complain when the returned queryset is invoked on other methods.

```
def func() -> Iterable[User]:
    return User.objects.all()

users = func()
users.filter(email__startswith='support')
```

MyPy output

```
"Iterable[User]" has no attribute "filter"
```

Answer (score 9):

IMHO, the proper way to do it is to define a type that inherits `QuerySet` and specify a generic return type for the iterator.

```py
    from django.db.models import QuerySet
    from typing import Iterator, TypeVar, Generic, Optional

    T = TypeVar("T")


    class QuerySetType(Generic[T], QuerySet):  # QuerySet + Iterator

        def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
            pass

        def first(self) -> Optional[T]:
            pass

        # ... add more refinements
```

Then you can use it like this:

```py
users: QuerySetType[User] = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
   print(user.email)  # typing OK!
user = users.first()  # typing OK!
```

Answer (score 8):

You actually can do what you want if you import the annotations module:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

def my_function() -> QuerySet[MyModel]:
    return MyModel.objects.all()
```

Neither MyPy nor the Python interpreter will complain or raise exceptions on this (tested on python 3.7). MyPy will probably be unable to type-check it, but if all you want is to document your return type, this should be good enough.

Comment: This works well for Python 3.9 (then even without `from __future__ import annotations`)

Answer (score 4):

```
from typing import Iterable

def func(queryset_or_list: Iterable[MyModel]): 
    pass
```

Both of queryset and list of model instance is iterable object.

Answer (score 1):

I've found myself that using `typing.Sequence` to solve a similar issue:

```
from typing import Sequence


def print_emails(users: Sequence[User]):
    for user in users:
        print(user.email)


users = User.objects.all()


print_emails(users=users)
```

As far as I know from docs:

> A Sequence is anything that supports len() and .**getitem**(), independent of its actual type.

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import (TypeVar, Generic, Iterable, Optional)
from django.db.models import Model
from django.db.models import QuerySet
_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=Model)


class QuerySetType(Generic[_T], QuerySet):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterable[_T]:
        pass

    def first(self) -> Optional[_T]:
        pass
```