# Type Hint for Django model with annotated field

Tags: python, django, type-hinting, django-stubs

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```
class Toolbox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tools = models.ManyToManyField("Tool")

class Tool(models.Model):
    class Size(models.TextChoices):
        SMALL = "S"
        MEDIUM = "M"
        LARGE = "L"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Size.choices)
```

I have a function to get all small tools for each toolbox. The argument type hint comes from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44321011/6611672):

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet

def get_toolbox_to_small_tools_mappings(
    toolboxes: QuerySet | list[Toolbox],
) -> dict[Toolbox, list[Tool]]:
    return {toolbox: toolbox.small_tools for toolbox in toolboxes}
```

The idea here is to require users of this function to prefetch this `small_tools` field using `prefetch_related()` to reduce the number of db hits and speed up the code:

```
toolboxes = Toolbox.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "tools",
        queryset=Tool.objects.filter(size=Tool.Size.SMALL),
        to_attr="small_tools",
    )
)
toolbox_to_small_tools_mappings = get_toolbox_to_small_tools_mappings(toolboxes)
```

This all works great but mypy is complaining with the following error:

> error: "Toolbox" has no attribute "small_tools"  [attr-defined]

Is there anyway to fix this?

The `WithAnnotations[Model]` type from django-subs ([see here](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs#how-do-i-annotate-cases-where-i-called-querysetannotate)) is an option but it's [buggy](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/763).

Answer (score -1):

Your best options may be to use type annotations from django-stubs or disable annotations (type: ignore).

One alternative option is to switch to using `getattr`, but this has down-sides (see below).

```py
from django.db.models import QuerySet

def get_toolbox_to_small_tools_mappings(
    toolboxes: QuerySet | list[Toolbox],
) -> dict[Toolbox, list[Tool]]:
    return {toolbox: getattr(toolbox, "small_tools") for toolbox in toolboxes}
```

This keeps things simple, and maintains the same functionality, but at the cost of affecting refactoring tools and other developer IDE functionality that won't be able to translate this code.

Comment: I disagree.  Refactor tools won't translate this kind of code.  Would be better to use (even if buggy) type annotations and defer "fixing" it until typehints are first class citizens

Comment: @boatcoder, I agree and I hadn't really thought about the impact on refactoring tools. I will update my answer to say it's not a good approach.